# Angular with Oracle

Tags: node.js, angular, oracle, tomcat, oracle-ords

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to build applications using Angular/ORDS/Oracle, i am new to this web stack. What i understood so far is we need one front end / back end / database to build entire application.

in general we use Angular/Nodejs/Sql Server to develop application. in this Angular is front ent/ Node js is used to build backend or web services. Sql server is the database.

Is there a good example or resource to learn how to build apps using Angular/ORDS/Oracle with one CRUD example.

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle and ORDS, you'll just define some REST Services to feed data to your Angular app.

You'll hopefully be making VERY similar, GET, PUT, POST, & DELETE calls as you were doing before.

You can 'shape' the Service templates to have the mapping that you want. They are then back-ended by Oracle SQL and/or PL/SQL that runs in the database.

ORDS handles paging the results and transforming everything in and out of the database to {json}

I have lots of resources for you [getting started with REST Services in Oracle here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/oracle-rest-data-services-ords/)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, i will go through the great stiff. Is it necessary to know Java or code in jave to understand and implement tomcat apache server. Is tomcat similar to IIS and node server.

Comment: Tomcat can make ORDS easier to manage, but it's not required. You can run ORDS as a standalone program, it comes with its own Webserver (Jetty) - no need to know Java to install, operate, or code for ORDS

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff.